# Python Script Locking SQL Server in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, locking

I'm running very short script that executes this query:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='myServer', database='myDB',               
           trusted_connection='yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (ID, Sale, Quantity) VALUES (176, 2.0, 35.0), (176, 2.5, 62.0), (176, 3.0, 89.0), (176, 3.5, 154.0), (176, 4.0, 225.0), (176, 4.5, 365.0)")
cursor.close()
```

When I try to retrieve the data that was just inserted, the query locks up and keeps executing without returning anything. I have to kill the process to free things up. When I execute the same query inside SQL Server 2008 it works fine. Advice on debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the query that's causing the problem...

Comment: Your questions says `When I try to retrieve the data that was just inserted, the query locks up...` - the only query in your question is an `INSERT` statement.  Where is the `SELECT` statement that gets locked up?

Comment: Select id, sale quantity from table where id  = 176

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using executemany and you also need a commit statement following your inserts.

```
vals = [ (176, 2.0, 35.0), (176, 2.5, 62.0), (176, 3.0, 89.0), (176, 3.5, 154.0), (176, 4.0, 225.0), (176, 4.5, 365.0)]
cursor.executemany("""
                  INSERT INTO myTable
                  (ID, Sale, Quantity)
                  VALUES (?,?,?)
                  """, vals)
cnxn.commit()
```